# Font name of a specific character in a string | Swift

Tags: string, swift, fonts

is it possible to get the font name and its size of a specific character in string in Swift?

I want to make a textview in which you can type with different fonts. I did this, but the problem is for example if something, lets say "hello" is written in Helvetica 16pt, and my current font Helvetica 24 pt, and then I want to write something more in "hello", let say "helloworld". This is possible in swift using attributed strings, but the word "hello" will be 16pt, and the word "world", will be 24pt. So, how to detect the font of the "hello" word, and then change the font automatically, and continue typing with the same font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [NSAttributedString documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html). The font size attribute you mentioned is actually contained within the `NSFontAttributeName` key, which stores an `NSFont` which has both font type and size. You can directly access that using `fontAttributesInRange:` if you know where you want to look in the string.

Comment: is it ok if I use "enumerateAttribute" to detect the font attribute?

Comment: Sure, you just have to check for the key `NSFontAttributeName`

Comment: // NSMakeRange selectedrange - 1
composeTextView.attributedText.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, inRange: NSMakeRange(0, 3), options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (value, range, stop) -> Void in
                if let aFont = value as? UIFont {

}